# Check input fields depending on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

[View image of form here before reading the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzsii.png)

Using jQuery when the `Complete Safety Walk` button is pressed I want to make sure that if any radio buttons are set to `Fail` that the `Action Required`, `Assigned To` and `ECD` fields for that row are not empty and the `Complete Safety Walk` button gets disabled.

The table has an id `safety_walk_items` and each row has a unique id `item_1`, `item_2`, etc.

**Note:** There are NO form open/close elements as each row is saved using AJAX (when the icon at the end of the row is clicked).

I'm not using any fancy input highlighting, just showing a hidden div with an error message.

`<div class="validation_errors hidden"></div>`

Comment: This sounds like a super simple `if` statement. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: If those fields "are not empty", what should be present in those fields when Fail is checked?

Comment: @CalebAnthony Nothing yet as I've no idea how to iterate over each row.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob Action Required should have text and ECD should have a date. The Assigned To will always have a selection.

Comment: Can you post the html for your table? That will give us an idea about how to answer the question for your specific situation

Comment: [see this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keithmclaughlin/3ax0v8qd/2/)